# PostgreSQL 9.4 - syntax error at or near "IF" - inside function

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I'm getting the *ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF"* error form the following sample code.

Note: I did replace the queries to ease complexity.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_return_dev(
"Title" character varying,
"ID" character varying)
RETURNS x_returntype AS $$

select item from table1

IF NOT found THEN
select item from table2
END IF;
$$
```

Any suggestion would help!

Comment: I would expect a `begin`/``end` block as well as a `return` statement.

Comment: Instead of scaring away a new user with down votes or off-the-cuff comments, why not help the guy on his way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be confused about the language of the function. You structure the function as if it is a SQL language function (no `BEGIN` \ `END` statements), but you use elements of the PL/pgSQL language. Since you obviously need the additional features of PL/pgSQL (conditional branching), I would suggest that you start by learning [how a PL/pgSQL function is structured](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-structure.html).

[A `SELECT` statement returning a single row](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) inside of a PL/pgSQL function needs a target to store its result.

If you need to [return a result from a function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING), you need a `RETURN` statement inside the function body.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_return_dev(
  "Title" character varying,
  "ID" character varying)
  RETURNS x_returntype AS $$
DECLARE
  item_var   same_type_as_item_column;
  return_var x_returntype;
BEGIN
  SELECT item INTO item_var FROM table1;

  IF NOT found THEN
    SELECT item INTO item_var FROM table2;
  END IF;

  -- Do your processing
  ...
  return_var := ...;

  RETURN return_var;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```